# Binding doesn't update with the view's TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox, dependency-properties

I have this `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="32" Text="{Binding DMinRange, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Which is connected to the ViewModel's `DMinRange` dependency prop:

```
        public string DMinRange
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DMinRangeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DMinRangeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DMinRangeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DMinRange", typeof(string), typeof(Spectrum), new UIPropertyMetadata("0"));
```

and is getting updated correctly (I printed a `MessageBox` which doesn't show a zero but the `TextBox` still shows *zero*)

the dependency is getting update with this method:

```
public void UpdateRange()
{
    // need to provide some validation
    DMinRange = MinRange.ToString();
    DMaxRange = MaxRange.ToString();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here that my `TextBox` doesn't gets updated?

Comment: Why you limit your TextBox binding mode to OneWay? Is it for reading only?

Comment: Yes, Because i need to put some validation on the Textbox if it get's changed on the view before the actual dependency is changed.

Comment: Please read [Dependency Property Callbacks and Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx) for a proper implementation.

Comment: Just a comment: ViewModels shouldn't have DependencyProperties. These are a WPF feature, and ViewModels should be View-agnostic (that is, not dependant on UI technology).